# undefined method in link to parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I have this database structure

[image]

the configuration in routes.rb is like this

```
resources :polls do
    resources :subpolls
end

resources :subpolls do
    resources :preguntas
end

resources :preguntas do
    resources :respuestas
end
```

at this moment I'm in the "respuestas" model in index.html.erb file, and I Want a link_to called "back" to go back to preguntas model, so I have it this way

index.html.erb

```
<% link_to "Back", subpolls_preguntas_path(@preguntas.subpoll_id) , class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

But I got this error

```
undefined method `subpoll_id' for nil:NilClass
```

The relations in models are ok

Can somebody tell me please how to fix it.

Comment: You will have to initialize `@preguntas` in your `RespuestasController`.

Comment: Show your controller code. As @Vimsha mentioned, you don't initialize `@preguntas` instance variable.

Comment: This is like I have the controller http://pastebin.com/X0w6aAqh look this method before_action :find_pregunta_respuesta, and that method works ok when I come back from preguntas to subpolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are in the respuestas model and in the index page, so you may reference the parent object as @pregunta and not @preguntas

Comment: Thanks man :D I didn't need to define @preguntas again. I just change this: subpolls_preguntas_path(@preguntas.subpoll_id) for this subpoll_preguntas_path(@pregunta.subpoll_id)

Answer (score 0):

Simply read the exception message:

> undefined method `subpoll_id' for nil:NilClass

When you do `@preguntas.subpoll_id`, ruby tells you that it can't call the methode `subpoll_id` on `nil`.

You have to initialize `@preguntas` as an instance of your `Pregunta` model.